# Cannot echo value of session customer I'd?

Tags: php

I really have no clue what is going on here, i am getting quite frustrated debugging this. 
I verified the the details i entered exist in the table yet the login simply goes back to index.php without an error msg, where instead it should go to order.php.

```
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['customer_loggedin']))
{
    header('Location:order.php');
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    include 'php/db_config.php';

    $login = trim($_POST['login']);
    $password = trim($_POST['password']);

    if($login && $password)
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer WHERE (code=:code OR phone=:phone OR businessName=:businessName OR email=:email) AND password=:password";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue(':code', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':phone', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':businessName', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $login, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindValue(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
              $id = $row['id'];
              $_SESSION['customer_loggedin'] = 1; 
              $_SESSION['customer_id'] = $id;
            header('location:order.php');
        }
        else
            {
            header('Location:index.php');
            $_SESSION['errmsg'] = 'Incorrect Login Details';
            die;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot echo the ID of the session value from customer Id.

The reason here is I want to be able to select something from the table later on using the logged in user Id.

Comment: If i set session to = 1 then i can loggin but i cannot display session userid

Comment: In this script `$conn` is not defined

Comment: $conn is from the include file.

Comment: `$row['id']` is defined? (My guess - no)

Comment: What do you mean by defined, I just added to the code $id=$row['id']

Comment: But what's the value of `$row`, I believe it should be the results of the query but you don't fetch it. In other words, if you `var_dump($row)` - what do you get?

Comment: I do not get anything when i dump the variable, just blank. How would i go about fetching the data if its not fetching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, the problem is that you're trying to store an undefined variable in the session.

```
$_SESSION['customer_id'] = $id; //$id = $row['id']
```

I believe that $row has meant to be the results of your query but you just didn't fetch it. `$row` is undefined and `$row['id']` is also undefined.

You should add the following code in order to fetch the results of your query:

```
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Right after the condition:

```
if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
```

Comment: OMG your a genius! I have tried over a few hours trying to debug this, bear in mind im new to PHP. You saved me such a headache :O

Comment: You're welcome, Please approve my answer if it helped you. Good luck :)